# Different styling for different tooltips on a single page?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, google, tooltips, consistency

I am working on a web application, and we are focusing very much on the  consistency of the look&feel. When we are designing tooltip styles, we can see there is the 'plain style' tooltip and all kinds of styled tooltips. Like the bootstrap one for example.

Below is the example of a plain tooltip:

[image]

Below is ab example of a 'styled tooltip':
[image]

It's very natural to think that on the same page, the same style of tooltip should be used, right? but actually Google Drive used both of them in one page, and very close to each other.

As the picture below shows, in the top right corner of google drive, all ICONs in group A will use the 'plain style tooltip'; whereas all the ICONs in group B will use the 'styled tooltip'.

Is there a likely UX reason for this difference?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**This is a bug with the Google UI, and not intentional.**

You were right to notice the distinction, but it shouldn't be used as any kind of example of good design.

As of now (March 2015), Google is in the middle of a long process of migrating its apps and platforms to [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html), and it will take a while before most apps are compliant.

Material Design has specific guidelines for consistent tooltips which can be found [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tooltips.html#). Eventually, Google tooltips should be moved to comport with Material Design guidelines, and look like this:

[image: tooltips]

Comment: s/bug/feature-request/g :-)

Comment: I would not call that a bug - it's just a fact of life that you can not practically migrate a complex set of programs from one style to another at the same time. So you expect and accept they will be different for some time.

Comment: @Aaronaught From this perspective, it's not even a feature request. Its a planed transition phase, that was known before, and planed for. There is no need to handle this problem; it will just be away when the migration is finished.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I think you will find that there are lots of issues which UX professional consider bugs which are not considered bugs for app developers (and vice versa!).  It's caused enough (un)healthy debate in that many companies just use separate UX and dev issue tags and closeouts to deal with this :-)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel ....UX-dev is some kind of tragic love story in most companies :-)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Well it won't go away by itself. Someone has to implement it, which means it has to be planned and scheduled. Generally I call that a feature, although if it's inconsistent enough to be seriously confusing to users then it might get escalated to bug.

Comment: @Aaronaught Sorry, I did not explain clearly - in part it's in my own answer. What I mean is: There is already a general plan to migrate that software module from an old  style guide to use of a new UI style guide. That is indeed a long process, and it is expected and planed. And this overall process will include switching to the new icons, because they are specified in the new style guide. There is nothing extra to plan, because it was planed long ago when exactly to do that, in a project "general UI style migration". Does that make any sense? Maybe I missed some point?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: No, I wouldn't say that you missed anything. You just might be underestimating the number of these migrations going on at once.

Comment: @Aaronaught I see, we are just conting different things: I count there is one global migration project, that roughly consists of the decision to do the migration, and then getting all the product or module migrations planed and done, trying to get each UI change combined piggi-backed on some other change that needs to be done. Whether they get done in parrallel or not depends mainly on available ressources, like developers, testers, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure it's because Drive is developped by another team than the team who's working on the Google account canvas. More a question of schedule/production rather than UX/UI thought I guess.

Comment: This is definitely spot on, at google there are so many products with so many teams trying to integrate all these applications is tough.  For instance, the google products page has a set of css rules that most of the other google sites have to use / abide by.  But when you get to the nitty gritty of things such as tool tips these may differ.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the upper and the lower part belong to **two different software products**.
The upper one implements the UI to the user account, and handles the navigation.
The lower part belongs to the current application.

I assume they where created at **different times**. Between these, there was a change in the **style guide** used, regarding how to style tooltips.

So one part is just **more up to date** regarding style, and I expect the other part will be changed to that style as part of a future UI update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an authoritative answer BUT the two tool tips refer to different environments and Google's designers might have wanted to differentiate between them.

The first, "plain," tooltip is for Google's main navigation section.

The second, "styled," tooltip is for the individual app within the broader Google environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the native tooltip if possible (if you're not trying to do a fancy tooltip with icons or colors). This will be most familiar to users and you don't have to worry as much about accessibility, etc. in the way you do when you use a custom solution.